# How long can anonymised log files be stored in the EU?

Tags: logging, gdpr

It seems to be standard industry practice to anonymise IP addresses etc. in web server log files after seven days. If this has happened, how long am I allowed to keep the log files? My reason for keeping them is for possible analysis in the event of an attack that is only noticed and/or processed after seven days (this has already happened to me). I sleep more peacefully when I don't have to delete log files at all, although I already realise that this is not an argument. I expect a statement of the form one month, one year, three years or forever (archived).